# Indicar la repetición de valores consecutivos mediante una tupla. Python

Tags: python, lista, tuplas

```
a=[1,1,1,3,5,4,1,3,3,4,4]
```

Desde una lista suministrada, debo indicar cuales valores consecutivos se repiten y empaquetar el resultado mediante una tupla.

Por ejemplo, de la lista en referencia, se debe devolver:
[(1,3),(3,1),(5,1),(1,2),(3,2)]

```
d=[]
for i in a:
    if i==a[]:
        cont+=1
        temp1=i
        temp2=cont+i
    d.append(temp2)
p(d)
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa el código que adjuntas? Es incorrecto incluso a nivel de sintaxis ya que ¿qué se supone que hace `i==a[]` por ejemplo? ¿Y qué es la función `p()`?

Comment: `res=[(e, a.count(e)) for e in set(a)]`

Comment: Christian, gracias por tu aporte !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que te podría servir el siguiente codigo, de acuerdo al ejemplo que muestras:

```
a=[1,1,1,3,5,4,1,3,3,4,4]

#calculos
unique_numbers=set(a) #set trae solo valores unicos
lista=[]
for number in unique_numbers:
    lista.append((number,a.count(number)))
```

el resultado es:

```
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 1)]
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, si bien tu código es correcto y la respuesta también, se recomiendo no responder a preguntas que no demuestren un esfuerzo por resolver el problema, ya que prácticamente le haz hecho la tarea al autor de la pregunta. Por favor haz el [tour] y también recomiendo que leas [ask]

Comment: Esta respuesta no hace lo que se pide, ya que no cuenta valores **consecutivos**. Por ejemplo, cuentas 4 unos, pero solo hay 3 consecutivos y uno "suelto" más adelante.

Comment: abulafia, Gracias por tu aporte !

Como lo reseñaste, en el comentario anterior, el codigo no realiza lo requerido, por tal motivo hice la consulta.
La respuesta debe mostrar, en forma de tuplas dentro de una lista, el numero de veces que se repite un valor de forma consecutiva.
Aclaro que estoy iniciando y de manera autodidacta en la programación, por lo que pido disculpa  si los errores son obvios